# Style view like iphone appstore app?

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

I want to style a view similar to iPhone Appstore app. I don't understand how the view is laid using IB or is it laid programatically.

[image: Appstore Featured View]

I dont know. Are they multiple collection view laid on scrollview or is it one collection view with some custom layout or table view. 
Also every collection view is scrolling horizontally and having Header-type on the top where one can click on SEE ALL >  .. it cant be header supplementary view because it will be then on the left as scrolling is horizontally and not on top.. how is this done

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row is a custom `UITableViewCell` with horizontal `UITableView` in it and this horizontal `UITableView` has another custom `UITableViewCell` to represent one app on the horizontal list. Thus, users are being able to make vertical and horizontal scrolls.

For the header-type and See All button you can use the following UITableViewDelegate method:

> -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

The following article makes similar output with `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` that contains horizontal `UITableView`.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Comment: I developed a control that can be used for that approach and uploaded to the github. https://github.com/polatolu/POHorizontalList

Comment: Cheers pal.. great help !!